# Arduino Due Sam3X8E accessing timer value

Tags: c, timer, arm, arduino

Im using Arduino Due which has An Atmel core SAM3X8E i need to start the SAM3X8E timer and reading value directly form the timer any one has an example of how to start SAM3X8E timer and reading values directly  form it
here is the steps

1- setting the timer to count clock cycle (i also want the SAM3X8E to run on 84Mhz)

2- start timer

3- accessing timer reg and gets its value

4- stop the timer form counting

plz if u have any example (preferred in C)

Comment: Any timer in particular?  IIRC, SAM3X8E has three GP timer/counters.  It's all there in the user manual.

Comment: timer/counter TC not the real-time timer RTC

Comment: and i want to use TC0 
actually i was wondering how to start and configure the timer

Answer (score 2):

I recommend the following [DueTimer](https://github.com/ivanseidel/DueTimer) library. It should fit your need. 
If not it should provide enough example in its source code for you to get what you want.

Along with the [forum thread](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=130423.0) that details a lot about the SAM3X8E timers